# Restrict controller action from web site only

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

Is it possible to restrict controller action access for my action methods to AJAX-only requests?

I mean that a non-Ajax request to action it will be redirected to 404 or error thrown. Action will only return the correct result, if request is made by JS on my own page.

I tried to google it, but didn't found an answer. I learned that I can implement custom filter for that purpose, but maybe it exists in MVC already?

Thank you.

Comment: I'm a little lost about your intention. Do you want to block unauthorized requests from unauthenticated or wrong role users?

Comment: I want to block only direct request to action (when someone types "www.mysite.com/controller/action" in browser URL bar).

Comment: HttpPostAttribute is enough to block from browser bar;)

Comment: @Olexander, would non-Ajax posts be acceptable to OP?

Comment: @DaveA, yes they would, and you are absolutely correct with your answer, even more, your solution doesn't lead to probable rewriting of existing jquery `$.get()` and `$.getJSON()` requests. But considering the comment above (about the browser URL bar), POST requests is what @AlexDn is trying to reach (well it looks like:). That's why I left a comment only and not a post;)

Comment: @Olexander HttpPostAttribute is good solution, but in my case it will allow posting from "external" sites. I want to allow AJAX from my site only.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

create a custom action method selector to block non-Ajax calls

```
public class AjaxOnlyAttribute : ActionMethodSelectorAttribute
{
    public override bool IsValidForRequest(ControllerContext controllerContext, MethodInfo methodInfo)
    {
        return controllerContext.HttpContext.Request.IsAjaxRequest();
    }
}
```

Your attribute would be applied in the classic manner

```
[AjaxOnly]
public ActionResult Index()
{
```

Or you can apply it to your Controller

```
[AjaxOnly]
public class HomeController : Controller
{
```

I'm not sure I would recommend you send your users to a 404, but as always, the developer alone understands their requirements. So I recommend you consider if you would want to approach this in a "softer" fashion of redirecting to a warning page.

Comment: @IamStalker, feel zoned in today

Comment: It looks like I will need to create my attribute that will do it. In addition to IsAjaxRequest, I will to check that request is done from my site (url-refferer or something like that).